# What is the expected number of virus cells?

Tags: probability

Suppose there is a virus cell which either divides or doesn't divide into 2 daughter virus cells every second. The probability it does divide is $p$ and the probability it doesn't divide is $1-p$, where $p<1$. Then what is the expected number of virus cells after n seconds.

(Note that technically viruses are not composed of cells, however, for the sake of convince we shall call them cells)

Comment: a [virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virus) is not a cell, though it can infect one

Answer (score 1):

The situation can be accurately modelled by the binomial distribution. The Binomial distribution models situations in which there are multiple binary choices, i.e, one option has probability $p$ and the other has probability $1-p$. The expected value of this distribution is the number of choices multiplied by p.

Let $X$ be the number of cells after $n$ seconds. $X$ is modelled binomial with n events and probability p. Hence we have $np$ expected cells after n seconds.